# WordPress WooCommerce - How To Handle Customers With Multiple Shipping and Billing Addresses?

Tags: wordpress, e-commerce, woocommerce

Thanks in advance for your help. I am working with a client to develop a new ecommerce solution, and WooCommerce has always been a favorite of mine. But this client is different -- their customers sometimes have 10 or more shipping addresses and billing addresses. In general terms, how would you go about writing a custom script for this? I just need a good jumping off point to start at.

Comment: [Shipping Multiple Addresses](http://www.woothemes.com/products/shipping-multiple-addresses/) is handled by a  premium extension.

Answer (score 0):

Just add the extra addresses using filter `woocommerce_my_account_get_addresses`